# Render headline of first content element in Grid Container different

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, fluid-styled-content, tx-gridelements

Is it possible to render the headline of the first content element within a Grid Elements container different in the fluid_styled_content template or via TypoScript?

Comment: You mean with a different HTML? Maybe you could simply solve it with CSS?

Comment: That's how I did it now, but the possibility to have different markup would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several virtual fields within cObj->data that are created during the rendering process of Gridelements. So you might want to check for keys with the prefix **parentgrid_**

Additionally you can use

```
data = cObj:parentRecordNumber
```

to get the position of an element within the rendering order. Since Gridelements uses the sorting field of tt_content for the rendering of children and the parentRecordNumbers are handled correctly between different container columns, you should get the correct value - **1** - for the first element of each column there.